# Who were the aliens seen in this scene from The Phantom Menace (alongside the ET species)?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, object-identification

In the image below, we can see ET's species at the bottom left. Is the species at the *top right* of the image known in Star Wars lore?

[image]

Comment: Oogie boogies? Is Lucas a Tim Burton fan?

Comment: At first glance I thought the aliens from Peter Jackson's "Bad Taste"  (1987) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092610/mediaviewer/rm809113600

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are the [Swokes Swokes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Swokes_Swokes) delegation of senators, native to the planet of Makem Te.

[image]
<sub><sup>*Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia*</sup></sub>